# Не работает геолокация в Cordova

Tags: android, геолокация, cordova

Пишу приложение на Cordova. Использую плагин для геолокации. Когда тестировал в браузере, все работало хорошо. Сейчас пытаюсь запустить на Android и получаю ошибки:

```
E/cr_LocationProvider: Caught security exception while registering for location updates from the system. The application does not have sufficient geolocation permissions.
E/cr_LocationProvider: newErrorAvailable application does not have sufficient geolocation permissions.
```

Как их побороть? В манифест добавлял еще такие строки

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

Не помогло